# yum --installroot should use /etc/yum.repos.d?

Tags: yum, chroot

I have a chroot environment in a directory. I want to install some RPM packages using the repositories in that chroot environment instead of the host OS ones.

yum --installroot= will look for packages repositories only in myroot/etc/yum.repos.d or it will only/also look in /etc/yum/repos.d? RHEL 6 is having the latter behavior. If that is expected behavior, what is the best method to achieve what I need?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I you start `yum` from within the chroot, it will only look in `myroot/etc/yum.repos.d`. If you start it from the normal system, it will always look in `/etc/yum.repos.d`.

So just start `yum` from within chroot. Of course you will first have to install `yum` and everything needed for it in the chroot.

Answer (score 0):

For all yum dists you can define your own configuration by:

```
yum -c myyum.conf --installroot=....
```

and create the `myyum.conf` file e.g.

```
[main]
cachedir=/var/cache/yum/$basearch/$releasever
keepcache=1
debuglevel=1
logfile=/yum.log
exactarch=1
obsoletes=1
gpgcheck=1
plugins=1
installonly_limit=5
distroverpkg=centos-release
reposdir=./my_yum.repos.d/
metadata_expire=90m
http_caching=all
color=off
```

which will in this case look for the repos in `./my_yum.repos.d/`